# How do I read avro file as a list of objects in Java Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, avro, spark-avro

I have an avro file which i want to read and operate on after converting it to its representative object

I've tried loading it using RDD and DataSet in Java Spark but in both cases i'm unable to convert to the required object

As DataSet

```
Dataset<MyClass> input = sparkSession.read().format("com.databricks.spark.avro").load(inputPath)
                .as(Encoders.bean(MyClass.class));
```

This fails with error "Cannot have circular references in bean class, but got the circular reference of class class org.apache.avro.Schema"

As RDD

```
JavaRDD<String> input = sparkContext.textFile(inputPath);
```

How can I convert this RDD object to RDD object or Dataset object ?

I'm pretty new to this so pardon me if I'm missing something basic but unable to find a working solution.

Comment: What version of Spark are you using? The databricks library isn't needed for Spark 2.4.x. Can you remove the encoder?

Comment: Im on 2.3.0. without the encoder it doesn't compile

Comment: It doesn't compile with `Dataset<MyClass>`, but you can still create a dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved by using SparkAvroLoader from https://github.com/CeON/spark-utils